# How exactly does suppressing enemies work?

Tags: payday-2

I chose to concentrate my skill points in the [*Enforcer*](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Skills#Enforcer) skill tree, which has the *Oppression* skill. It can make weapons "more effective at suppressing enemies". To further understand how to take advantage of the 'Oppression' skill, I have these questions:

- Do I have to hit enemies before they get suppressed or will just firing in their general direction get them suppressed?
- How do I optimally lay down suppressing fire (for the different weapon types)?
- What exactly happens to enemies or what do they do when they get suppressed?
- What are the changes when I make my weapons "more effective at suppressing enemies"? (by putting skill points into the Oppressor skill [for Basic and Ace])

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "Threat" stat do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133310/what-does-the-threat-stat-do)

Comment: @Unionhawk This doesn't seem to be a duplicate question of that one. (Parts of the possible answers might be the same, but that doesn't mean it's a duplicate question.) Also, I specifically asked about enemy suppression in the context of the 'Oppression' skill here (which already existed before Update 13), not the weapons' "threat" stat. (e.g. What changes when I put skill points into Oppression?) I also asked about how to optimally lay down suppressing fire here, which is not asked about in that other question.

Comment: I suppose. But they're certainly related.

Answer (score 9):

Enemies will duck and either hit the ground or try to move out of the way while being suppressed, during which time they won't do much firing back at you or your team. Certain enemies are more susceptible to being suppressed - pretty much anything "non special" below the FBI guys in full armour - these guys and specials will generally keep charging at you although I have seen tasers act momentarily suppressed. This is especially useful when you're trying to move bags in line of sight of enemies.

Just firing in the general direction of enemies will trigger the chance to suppress. How effectively you suppress is based upon:

- Your "chance to suppress" (Enforcer tree)
- The noise your gun makes (Higher "threat" is better, silenced is bad)

Silenced weapons seem to act like a negative modifier to suppression, since the enemies don't "hear" the gunshots and therefore don't try and hide. Sticking one of the noise amplifier/threat increasing modifications (sharks teeth, fire breather, etc) to your weapon and increasing the noise it makes will improve your suppression.

This is further detailed on the inventory screen when looking at weapons:

[image]

The amount that your skills increase the effectiveness of a particular statistic is indicated in the "Skill" column.